# How to install libs for R arrow package on ubuntu without internet?

Tags: r, apache-arrow

I am working on Azure databricks and it's compute server is Ubuntu 18.04. I want to install [arrow](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/arrow/vignettes/install.html) R package but **without internet access** because of security reasons. I downloaded arrow tar file on my MacBook that has internet access and made it available in ubuntu for manual installation. I performed following steps:

1. Re-installed **build-essential** by downloading it from this link and uploaded to ubuntu and executed following bash command to make it available: `sudo dpkg -i /dbfs/FileStore/tables/build_essential_12_4ubuntu1_amd64.deb`
2. Installed **cpp11** as it is dependency mentioned on [cran](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/arrow/index.html): `R CMD INSTALL /dbfs/FileStore/tables/arrow_dir/cpp11_0_3_1.tar.gz`
3. Downloaded **arrow_4.0.1.tar.gz** from [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/arrow/index.html) and made it available on ubuntu.
4. [Here](https://arrow.apache.org/install/) I see required **C++ dependencies** to be available on ubuntu before installing the arrow package. How can I install these dependencies without access to internet?

Thanks for reading my question.

**Note:** A solution is suggested below and after execution of `./thirdparty/download_dependencies.sh $HOME/arrow-thirdparty` I get:

```
# Environment variables for offline Arrow build
export ARROW_ABSL_URL=/root/arrow-thirdparty/absl-0f3bb466b868b523cf1dc9b2aaaed65c77b28862.tar.gz
export ARROW_AWSSDK_URL=/root/arrow-thirdparty/aws-sdk-cpp-1.8.133.tar.gz
export ARROW_AWS_CHECKSUMS_URL=/root/arrow-thirdparty/aws-checksums-v0.1.10
export ARROW_AWS_C_COMMON_URL=/root/arrow-thirdparty/aws-c-common-v0.5.10.tar.gz
export ARROW_AWS_C_EVENT_STREAM_URL=/root/arrow-thirdparty/aws-c-event-stream-v0.1.5
export ARROW_BOOST_URL=/root/arrow-thirdparty/boost-1.75.0.tar.gz
export ARROW_BROTLI_URL=/root/arrow-thirdparty/brotli-v1.0.9.tar.gz
export ARROW_BZIP2_URL=/root/arrow-thirdparty/bzip2-1.0.8.tar.gz
export ARROW_CARES_URL=/root/arrow-thirdparty/cares-1.17.1.tar.gz
export ARROW_GBENCHMARK_URL=/root/arrow-thirdparty/gbenchmark-v1.5.2.tar.gz
export ARROW_GFLAGS_URL=/root/arrow-thirdparty/gflags-v2.2.2.tar.gz
export ARROW_GLOG_URL=/root/arrow-thirdparty/glog-v0.4.0.tar.gz
export ARROW_GRPC_URL=/root/arrow-thirdparty/grpc-v1.35.0.tar.gz
export ARROW_GTEST_URL=/root/arrow-thirdparty/gtest-1.10.0.tar.gz
export ARROW_JEMALLOC_URL=/root/arrow-thirdparty/jemalloc-5.2.1.tar.bz2
export ARROW_LZ4_URL=/root/arrow-thirdparty/lz4-v1.9.3.tar.gz
export ARROW_MIMALLOC_URL=/root/arrow-thirdparty/mimalloc-v1.7.2.tar.gz
export ARROW_ORC_URL=/root/arrow-thirdparty/orc-1.6.6.tar.gz
Failed downloading https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases/download/v3.14.0/protobuf-all-3.14.0.tar.gz
```

Comment: Do you run `./thirdparty/download_dependencies.sh` on your MacBook or the remote server?

Comment: on a remote ubuntu server

Comment: I believe you will need to run the download script on your MacBook.  It will download all the dependencies that you will need.  Then you will need to copy the files to the remote server manually.  Then you will need to specify the environment variables on the remote server.  However, the path in the environment variables should point to whatever location you copied the files to on the remote server.

Comment: I downloaded protobuf-all-3.14.0.tar.gz in mac and zipped all tar files and made them available on ubuntu. Now I am facing cmake installation issues. I posted a separate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68574971/error-when-bootstrapping-cmake-offline-installation-on-ubuntu

Answer (score 6):

Would it help to use the script mentioned in the link below to download the dependencies and put them somewhere you can then install them from?

There's some instructions here: https://arrow.apache.org/docs/developers/cpp/building.html#offline-builds

I've pasted them below in case the link expires, but you may want to check it for the most up to date version of these instructions.

> To enable offline builds, you can download the source artifacts yourself and use environment variables of the form ARROW_$LIBRARY_URL to direct the build system to read from a local file rather than accessing the internet.

> To make this easier for you, we have prepared a script thirdparty/download_dependencies.sh which will download the correct version of each dependency to a directory of your choosing. It will print a list of bash-style environment variable statements at the end to use for your build script.

```
# Download tarballs into $HOME/arrow-thirdparty
$ ./thirdparty/download_dependencies.sh $HOME/arrow-thirdparty
```

> You can then invoke CMake to create the build directory and it will use the declared environment variable pointing to downloaded archives instead of downloading them (one for each build dir!).

Comment: I get a failure to download one of the tar files. I updated my question with a note to show the output.

Comment: and it is present here: https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/tag/v3.14.0

Comment: but I am not sure if this is the only .tar file missing!

Comment: I downloaded protobuf-all-3.14.0.tar.gz in mac and zipped all tar files and made them available on ubuntu. Now I am facing cmake installation issues. I posted a separate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68574971/error-when-bootstrapping-cmake-offline-installation-on-ubuntu

Comment: I will accept this answer as soon I know it works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Starting in `arrow` 6.0.0, the package should successfully install from source when offline. It will have only basic features: you'll be able to work with Arrow data and feather files, but features like Parquet reading, S3, and compression libraries won't be available. There is also a new utility function, `create_package_with_all_dependencies()`, that you can run on a machine connected to the internet in order to produce a "fat" source package containing all third-party C++ dependencies. You can then copy this to your airgapped server. See https://arrow.apache.org/docs/r/reference/create_package_with_all_dependencies.html for details.