# Error when bootstrapping CMake: offline installation on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, cmake

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and I am trying to install [cmake](https://cmake.org/download/) (cmake-3.21.1.tar.gz) **without internet access** by executing the command:

```
export CC=/usr/bin/gcc
export CXX=/usr/bin/g++

./bootstrap
```

But this results in following error:

```
---------------------------------------------
CMake 3.21.1, Copyright 2000-2021 Kitware, Inc. and Contributors
---------------------------------------------
Error when bootstrapping CMake:
Cannot find appropriate C compiler on this system.
Please specify one using environment variable CC.
See cmake_bootstrap.log for compilers attempted.

---------------------------------------------
Log of errors: /dbfs/FileStore/tables/arrow_dir/cmake-3.21.1/Bootstrap.cmk/cmake_bootstrap.log
---------------------------------------------
```

I opened the `cmake_bootstrap.log` file but the content of this file is as following:

```
Checking whether '/usr/bin/gcc    ' works.
```

**This doesn't explain where is the problem!**

***Note:** There are already similar questions here but none of the solutions work for me. I am working on ubuntu that has **no internet access**, so my situation is different!*

This is what I have done so far:

1. Re-installed `build-essential` using `sudo dpkg -i /dbfs/FileStore/tables/build_essential_12_4ubuntu1_amd64.deb`
2. Made sure gcc and g++ are installed, executed following:

   ```
   which gcc
   which g++
   ```

   it resulted in:

   ```
   /usr/bin/gcc
   /usr/bin/g++
   ```
3. Then I checked versions of **gcc** and **g++** at `/usr/bin/gcc` and `/usr/bin/g++`:

   ```
   export CC=/usr/bin/gcc
   export CXX=/usr/bin/g++
   $CC --version
   $CXX --version
   ```

   This resulted in:

   ```
   gcc (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0
   Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
   This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
   warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

   g++ (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0
   Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
   This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
   warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
   ```
4. Made sure **make** is already available by running make, and it is available:

   ```
   GNU Make 4.1
   Built for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
   Copyright (C) 1988-2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
   License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
   This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
   There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
   ```

Therefore, make, gcc and g++ are present but still I cannot execute `./bootstrap` and neither I see logs in `cmake_bootstrap.log`. **How can I fix this issue without accessing internet?** Thanks for reading my question and looking forward to suggestions.

My ubuntu details are:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
Linux 0325-123141-frank631-10-48-11-75 5.4.0-1051-azure #53~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jun 18 22:32:58 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
amd64
```

Comment: Please post the content of `cmake_bootstrap.log`. The script is quite simple: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/blob/master/bootstrap#L1213

Comment: As mentioned above, the content of `cmake_bootstrap.log` is `Checking whether '/usr/bin/gcc    ' works.`
!

Comment: And there is nothing after it?

Comment: nothing, I also opened the file and checked it. It has only this line: `Checking whether '/usr/bin/gcc    ' works.`

Comment: Ok. Please try `sh -x ./bootstrap` and post some ending part of the output, ex. from `+ cmake_c_compiler=`. Or maybe also put `echo something` in `bootstrap` file somewhere above `for std in 11 99 90; do` and see if it shows up. The idea is to isolate where exactly it fails. (I guess at `break 4`?) Does ex. `bash ./bootstrap` work? What is your `/bin/sh` (dash? bash? etc)?

Comment: after executing `sh -x ./bootstrap`, the content of the output was too big so I put everything in `temp.txt` and made it available here: https://easyupload.io/7hto9s

Comment: The file is strangely formatted - it has some unicode characters. To redirect to a file, do for example `bash -x ./bootstrap 2>thefile >&2`. It's odd that `cmake_try_run` does not execute the compiler.. Do you have a function `cmake_try_run` defined anywhere? Is the content of `bootstrap` the same as on gitlab? Does your compiler work? What would be the output of `echo 'int main() {}' | gcc -xc - ; echo $? ; ./a.out`?

Comment: no I do not have cmake_try_run function. `echo 'int main() {}' | gcc -xc - ; echo $? ; ./a.out` shows me `0`

Comment: Why bother building it when you can use the pre-built binaries unzipped out of the download folder? You clearly have enough internet access to download the sources. Just download the binaries instead.

Comment: Yes Alex, I was able to install by downloading `cmake-3.21.1-linux-x86_64.sh` but not sure why couldn't install like this!